# Modifying href selector to exclude anchor tags

Tags: javascript, href, selector, target

Currently, this adds `target="_blank"` to all href that include *.pdf* in the URL, but also excludes URLs with *www.fakewebsiteurl.com* in it. I've been trying to modify it to also exclude anchor URLs, but I'm coming up short. What am I missing here?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    links.forEach(function(link){
        var href = link.getAttribute('href');

        if (href.match(/\.pdf$/)
            || !href.match(/^\/www.fakewebsiteurl.com/)
            || !href.match(/\#$/)) {
                link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not entirely clear what you want to exclude. Provide some examples

Comment: Some widgets on our CMS use the <a> tag but don't actually go to a different page, so they put # in the href. So when the widget is clicked, it goes to www.fakewebsiteurl.com#

Comment: If you've found a satisfactory answer, please mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the $ from your regex.

```
!href.match(/\#/)
```

Answer (score 0):

The term "anchor URLs" could be interpreted a few ways.

If you're talking about values that start with `#`, you probably want a regex of `/^#/`.

If you're talking about values that contain a `#`, you probably want a regex of `/#/`

If you're talking about values that are only a `#`, you probably want a regex of `/^#$/`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't terribly clear. I specifically mean <a href="#">, as some widgets on our site use this so they can use an <a> tag but not go to a different page.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a regex for that as well.